# Makefiles: reading a file with 'pure make syntaxis' (no shell commands)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I want to read the content of a text file and assign it to a variable in my makefile. I read the make manual **ch 8.6: The file function**, and wrote this simple snippet in my makefile:

```
# Snippet from my makefile

my_var = $(file < C:/full/path/to/my_file.txt)

all:
    @echo $(my_var)
```

I get the following error:

```
*** Invalid file operation: < C:/full/path/to/my_file.txt.  Stop.
```

I deliberately choose for the $(file ..) instead of the $(shell ..) function to read out the file. That's because my makefile should be as platform independent as possible. The $(file ..) function is pure makefile-syntax, whereas the $(shell ..) function contains shell-syntax.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reading from a file was added in make 4.2, I'm guessing you're using an older version.

Comment: aaw.. that hurts. Yes, I'm using make 4.1, which I downloaded from this site: http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=make   Thank you so much for pointing this out. Do you know where I can download make 4.2 for Windows 64-bit? Thank you so much @user657267 for helping me :-)

Comment: https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: @user657267 Is mingw.org deprecated ? I downloaded mingw + mingw-make here and I have a 3.82 version of make, plus the site seems no to have changed a lot since 2007.

Comment: @TimF "regular" mingw has been all but dead for quite some time, although I see there has been some movement recently. Most people have since jumped ship to mingw-w64, which is what STL's distro I linked above uses.

Comment: @user657267 Thanks for the information ! It's not that obvious just by looking at mingw.org.

Comment: @TimF Yeah I remember going through the same process 6 or 7 years ago, it goes to show just how little has changed on mingw.org. The latest VS is actually very up to date compared to back then though.

Comment: Tested right now with the mingw build from nuwen.net and the `$(file ...)` function correctly works.

Comment: Thanks so much guys. All of your comments helped me to get it working as well :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade to at least make 4.2 if you want to read files with `$(file <)`.

From http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS

> Version 4.2 (22 May 2016)
>
> - The $(file ...) function can now read from a file with $(file <FILE).   The function is expanded to the contents of the file.  The
>   contents are   expanded verbatim except that the final newline, if
>   any, is stripped.

Comment: Where did you find this? It's not obvious from the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) nor from any changelogs I could find.

Comment: @Lucas if you mean how did I find out it was added in 4.2, it's in the [NEWS file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS)