# How can I read a file using Make's `$(file <)` function?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to read a file using Make's `$(file)` function. The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Function) suggests something like:

`MYVAR = $(file < foo)`

should work since:

> When reading from a file, the file function expands to the verbatim contents of the file, except that the final newline (if there is one) will be stripped. Attempting to read from a non-existent file expands to the empty string.

But the above code just throws an "invalid file operation: < foo" error.

Comment: Run `make --version`, you'll probably find it's < 4.2, which is when reading using `file` was added.

Comment: Right, I'm using 4.1. The confusing part is that this version support writing but not reading from files. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Find out when features were added here: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefiles: reading a file with 'pure make syntaxis' (no shell commands)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080029/makefiles-reading-a-file-with-pure-make-syntaxis-no-shell-commands)

Comment: So, without version 4.2+, do `MYVAR := $(shell cat foo)` instead. Please note the `:=` operator which means the value of the variable should be immediately evaluated at definition time, i.e. once, rather than each time it's used.